# Rendered aspect ratio appears stretched even at 1:1

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, camera, resolution

I have the render aspect ratio set to 1:1 under the 'Output properties' tab.

[image]

And yet my scene is still coming out stretched like this

[image]

I also noticed that the width of the render is much wider than the output resolution. What else is affecting the aspect ratio/resolution? Thank you.

**I have figured it out. The aspect ratio in the image editor was different. I put it to 1:1 there and it fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

**I have figured it out. The aspect ratio in the image editor was different. I put it to 1:1 there and it fixed it.